# Disable attribute doesn't work with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to disable a Function app, by using the `Disable` attribute with an app setting:

```
[Disable("Disable")]
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 8 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
```

When compiling this function, the `function.json` looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "disabled": "Disable",
    ...
}
```

On my function app on Azure, I've defined the following app setting:

[image]

But when looking at the functions in the function app, the function is still disabled:

[image]

I was expecting the function not to be disabled, since the value of the app setting is `0`. I guess the function app is disabled if the value of the `disabled` field in json is true if not set to `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like portal UI issue to me. I created a Timer Function and followed your scenario. The function is shown as disabled in the portal, but it still runs on schedule.

If I change the setting from `0` to `1`, it's still shown as disabled, but also doesn't run anymore.

Update (thanks to @ahmelsayed):
See [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/2029) (and [related](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/949)). UI only handles truthy values for that property, which should be fixed.

Comment: I see. Did you create a compiled function through VS/VS Code or did you create the function through the portal?

Comment: @ThomasArdal I did it with portal

Comment: Do you mind sharing your function code? I just tried creating one through the portal, but the Disable attribute doesn't seem to work when looking at the generated code through kudu.

Comment: There are no attributes in the portal. I used default code for function, and set `"disabled": "Disabled"` in `function.json`

Comment: I just tried that. Doesn't work. Azure keeps running the function even though Disabled is set to 1. But you are right in the fact, that the portal always shows `(disabled)` in front of the function name, when disabled is set to a non boolean.

Comment: `Disabled = 1` in settings and `"disabled": "Disabled"` in `json` works like charm here: no executions in last 8 minutes

Comment: When clicking refresh in the monitor I don't see new executions either. But if reloading the page and going back to monitor, I see new invocations.

Comment: see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/949 and https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/2029 the UI only handles [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values for that property, which should be fixed.

Comment: @Mikhail You're right. I think that the UI bug may have confused me here. When trying again, I am in fact able to enable/disable functions by an app setting. But as pointed out in your answer and in other comments, there's a portal bug always showing disabled, when the value is not a boolean. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/2029).

Comment: actual bug is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/949